# Generate Bar Code in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I need to generate a `Bar Code` in my `Xamarin.Forms` project. I have found samples to scan Bar Code. Anyone has tried to generate the Bar Code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the ZXing library, you can not only scan barcodes but also generate them.

The sample repo can be found here: https://github.com/jfversluis/Blurry-ZXingBarcodeImageView and was created to answer another question here on StackOverflow about barcodes being blurry. But it also shows how to generate a barcode.

Basically, you just install the ZXing library onto your projects and add a `ZXingBarcodeImageView` to your page.

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BlurryZXing" x:Class="BlurryZXing.MainPage" xmlns:forms="clr-namespace:ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms;assembly=ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms" xmlns:zx="clr-namespace:ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms;assembly=ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms" xmlns:zxcm="clr-namespace:ZXing.Common;assembly=zxing.portable">
    <forms:ZXingBarcodeImageView 
        IsVisible="True"
        x:Name="QRCodeView"
        BarcodeFormat="QR_CODE" 
        HeightRequest="300"
        WidthRequest="300"
        BarcodeValue="-1">
        <zx:ZXingBarcodeImageView.BarcodeOptions>
            <zxcm:EncodingOptions Width="300" Height="300" />
        </zx:ZXingBarcodeImageView.BarcodeOptions>
    </forms:ZXingBarcodeImageView>
</ContentPage>
```

You can specify the format and value. Supported formats at time of writing are: UPC-A, UPC-E, EAN-8, Code 39, EAN-13, ITF, RSS-14, RSS-Expanded, QR Code, Code 93, Data Matrix, Code 128, Aztec (beta), Codabar, PDF 417 (beta), MaxiCode.

Don't forget to initialize the ZXing library in your platform projects, else it will show up empty. You can do this by adding:

```
// On iOS in your AppDelegate.cs in the FinishedLaunching method
ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.iOS.Platform.Init();
```

and

```
// On Android in the MainActivity.cs in the OnCreate method
ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.Android.Platform.Init();
```

Comment: Please don't forgot to accept it as an answer if it did!